# setup and Run KSQL on windows machine

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I was just wondering if it is possible to run KSQL on windows machine. I downloaded from https://www.confluent.io/product/ksql/ and not sure how to set up and run.

Thanks
MR

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to run it under Docker. You can find the [images on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/u/confluentinc/), and there are [Docker Compose files](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/5.1.0-post/examples/cp-all-in-one) to bring up the full stack as required.

Comment: I did download on ksql on docker. Was able to successfully run some simple commands. Is it possible to create stream from a file that has many json records on windows machine? I am also using .NET stack

Comment: @user2726975 The Confluent .NET Kafka client can produce JSON, yes. Whether or not from a file